# Image sitemap. Ok to use the ALT text as <image:title>?

Tags: seo, sitemap, images, xml-sitemap, screaming-frog

Screaming Frog uses the alt text of an image when i create a sitemap of a crawled site and places it in the image sitemap as .

Is this correct? Or should the actual image title be used as  in the image sitemap ?

Thank you

Comment: did you tried to add title attribute in your image ? Crôôôa !

Comment: i don't want to. My images only have alt , not titles. I presume if i were to add titel atributs to my images screaming from would use them. But, in this case is it ok if the sitemap has the mage:title with the actual alt text instead?

Comment: it is too specific to this software, you can ask them directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `alt` in image sitemap, but only as `<image:caption>`, as mentioned in Google's [documentation](https://goo.gl/SxhDnD)

Comment: The linked documentation doesn't describe the difference. There's `<image:caption> Optional A caption for the image.` and `<image:title> Optional The title of the image.`. I'm no wiser reading this documentation. If there's answer provided on linked pages, then please quote it and put into the SE answer. External sites tend to change,..